# HTML: How to give the user a hint to toggle full screen view when he/she opens the document?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I made some HTML slides which are best viewed in full screen mode.

I want to give the user some kind of hint to toggle full screen view when he/she opens the document.

For example, some text like "please press F11 to switch to full screen view" in center of the screen, maybe within a box or something, which then disappears after the user follows the guide and will not show again.

Is there a way to do this by adding some js code in the document?

I don't want to use an alert box or something that is way too abrupt.

Comment: Yes. Look into how to make a modal dialog using HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically 2 options. The more subtle one is placing an alert (not javascript alert, [Bootstrap alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/alerts/)) to the document, maybe to the top.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  Please press F11 to switch to full screen view!
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The other, much more aggressive approach is to use a [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/), which is more similar to a javascript alert.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal fade" id="fullscreenModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Please press F11 to switch to full screen view!
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#fullscreenModal').modal('toggle');
</script>
```

In both cases, you will need a cookie to store once the user has already seen your message, and later check for that cookie to decide if you want to show the message.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think both ways are decent. Maybe a modal is more easy (for me) to implement and customize.